# Angular $resource date string gets decoded

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular to perform a rest call to limit by date like so:

`endpoint.com/myAction?date=04/29/15`

But it gets decoded to this:
`endpoint.com/myAction?date=04%2F29%2F15`

I'm instantiating the angular $resource like so:

```
app.factory('SessionResource', function () {
    return $resource('endpoint.com', {date: '@date'}
});
SessionResource.get({date: '04/29/15'};
```

There a way to pass in my date query parameters as a string so that it doesn't get encoded/decoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as timestamp, that's better to be used as query string. 
Then you can convert back to your format when needed (I can suggest using momentjs http://momentjs.com/ to play with dates)